# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject given a string

Tags: java, android, json

I'm having issues with a JSON request. I'm attempting to read an API and parse it with this code (below). I already have the Async working (so far) once I get this I should be set. The error i'm getting is below in the logs.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;


public class jsonParser {

    //initialize
    static InputStream stream = null;
    static String result = " ";
    static JSONObject object =null;

    public jsonParser(){

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONfromURL (String url){
        //HTTP call
        try{
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 2048 * 16);
            StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String blah = builder.toString();
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new String(blah));
            JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Categories");

            for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++)
            {
                 object = data.getJSONObject(i);
                 String id = object.getString("id"); 
                 String value = object.getString("name"); 
                 Log.d("Item name: ", value);
            }




            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Http Error","Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            }


        return object;
    }
}
```

Error Logs below

```
05-12 02:49:44.553: E/Http Error(19288): Error in http connection org.json.JSONException: Value ["Categories",[[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]]] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
05-12 02:49:44.553: W/dalvikvm(19288): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fb6438)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at com.example.hstnc_activity.DisplayServiceActivity$Request.onPostExecute(DisplayServiceActivity.java:116)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at com.example.hstnc_activity.DisplayServiceActivity$Request.onPostExecute(DisplayServiceActivity.java:1)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-12 02:49:44.563: E/AndroidRuntime(19288):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is what I should be getting back and dealing with via the server

```
["Categories",[[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]]]
```

Comment: What is at line 116 of `DisplayServiceActivity`?

Comment: directory = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DIRECTORY);
also higher up on line 40 
private static String TAG_DIRECTORY = "Categories";

Comment: `json` is `null`. Have we had this dance before?

Comment: I'm working with someone who may be asking similar questions. I can deal with that particular error once I'm able to fix the JSONObject error. Every tutorial i've read inserts a String and yet when I do it it errors out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html

Try

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(blah));
```

Instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new String(blah));
```

JSON example in your question is actually a JSON array.

So as a result, it is going to be

```
...
    public JSONObject getJSONfromURL (String url){
        //HTTP call
        try{
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 2048 * 16);
            StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String blah = builder.toString();

            //Parsing string into JSONArray
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(new String(blah));


            for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++)
            {
                 object = data.getJSONObject(i);
                 String id = object.getString("id"); 
                 String value = object.getString("name"); 
                 Log.d("Item name: ", value);
            }




            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Http Error","Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            }


        return object;
    }


..
```

---

Here is some explaination on what is going on with your JSON data.
Currently it looks like :

```
["Categories",[[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"} ....

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(new String(blah));
JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Categories");
```

Is not going to work because there is no object inside this JSON data called "Categories", instead it has a String element with value "Categories".

What you should really do is reform your JSON representation into

```
 {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"} .... }
```

So parser can figure out the JSON object called "Categories".

Here is a recommendation reading on writing JSON syntax.

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
```

In addition, here is a JSON validation tool to quickly debug / correct JSON syntax

```
http://jsonlint.com/
```

Comment: I updated my code to your suggestion and now receive the following in logcat:
`05-12 03:09:22.185: E/Http Error(21193): Error in http connection org.json.JSONException: Value Categories at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Excellent thank you. I'll updated the code in the morning and let everyone know how it goes.

Comment: Just so anyone who finds this, once the JSON data was formatted correctly, it seemed to work perfectly here is the new output
`{"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}`

Answer (score 0):

You must considerate two things:

1. The json response correspond to `JSONArray` not `JSONObject`.
2. The `"Categories"` entry in your json response is not an `JSONArray` by the format  of your response.

your should try this.

```
JSONObject rawJson = new JSONObject ( jsonResponse );
JSONArray categories = rawJson.getJSONArray( "Categories" );
```

with this json format

```
{"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
```